# CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing a react native application that uses sso from microsoft azure to log a user into the app.

I've picked up this library and it seems to be working fine, however when i try to get the user info it return s "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217.

I've tried the fixes from elsewhere on the internet to no avail.

My authorization header is

```
headers: {
         'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.token.accessToken,
}
```

I've also set up the permissions correctly aswell, is it just a library issue and i need to change libraries or is it something I'm doing wrong.

My LoginScreen Class

```
export default class SSOScreen extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const CREDENTIAILS = {
        client_id: '<client_id>',
        client_secret: '<client_secret>',
        scope: 'User.ReadBasic.All',
        redirect_uri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient'
    };
    this.azureInstance = new AzureInstance(CREDENTIAILS);
    this._onLoginSuccess = this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this);

  }
  render() {
      console.log(this.azureInstance);

      return (
          <AzureLoginView
          azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
          loadingMessage="Requesting access token"
          onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
       />
   );
  }
  _onLoginSuccess(){
      this.azureInstance.getUserInfo().then(result => {
         console.log(result);
      }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
      })
  }
}
```

If I log this.azureInstance.token in onLoginSuccess i get

```
Object {
  "accessToken": undefined,
  "expires_in": NaN,
  "refreshToken": undefined,
}
```

Comment: Same problem with React-native-azure-ad-2 did you find a fix?